# DataBase connection problem with PHPUnit and WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cli, unit-tests

I'm trying to run PHPUnit to unittest a WordPress plugin, but the error below keeps showing up.

```
Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in /private/tmp/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1452
```

I used WP-CLI to setup the unittests, but also WP-CLI throws a similar error when I try to run it.

I use MAMP to run the database.

I have setup WP-CLI and PHPUnit as phars, that are aliased in ~/.bash-profile, and ran with the default "php" supplied by OS X. Changing this, and running WP-CLI and PHPUnit with the latest PHP version supplied by MAMP fixed WP-CLI(It was running and connecting to the database just fine) but PHPUnit was still throwing the same error.

I have tried editing the wp-config.php file, and setting the host to ":/path/to/mamp/mysql.socket", "localhost:/path/to/mamp/mysql.socket" and "127.0.0.1", none of which helped.

I'm totally stuck, and don't know what to try next.

Comment: There is also a `wp-tests-config.php` file, which takes priority when running the unit tests. Maybe you need to add your database connection details there as well.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Feel free to post an answer, so you can get the reputation you rightfully have earned :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running the PHPUnit tests, WordPress will load the config from `wp-tests-config.php` instead of `wp-config.php`. You need to add your database connection details in `wp-tests-config.php`.

And if you use MAMP or AMPPS to host your database, you will have to use 127.0.0.1 as DB_HOST instead of localhost. Alternatively use the PHP version supplied by the Solution stack of choice, or set DB_HOST to ':/path/to/soulution/stack/mysql.socket'.

Comment: Thought I would note that if installed with WP-CLI as per https://pippinsplugins.com/unit-tests-wordpress-plugins-introduction/, there may be TWO directories that need to be considered: `/private/tmp/wordpress` and `/private/tmp/wordpress-tests-lib`